# C# how to trigger an alert when all picturebox has a value

Tags: c#

I'm creating a memory game for my schoolproject and i have a problem of triggering a messagebox when player won the game and displays a note "You hav matched all cards!". Does anyone have the solution.

One part of the code:

```
private void Card1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Card1.Image = Properties.Resources.car1;
    if(usedCard1 == null)
    {
        usedCard1 = Card1;
    }
    else if(usedCard1 != null && usedCard2 == null)
    {
        usedCard2 = Card1;
    }
    if(usedCard1 != null && usedCard2 != null)
    {
        if(usedCard1.Tag == usedCard2.Tag)
        {
            usedCard1 = null;
            usedCard2 = null;
            Card1.Enabled = false;
            Dupcard1.Enabled = false;
            points = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreCounter.Text);
            points = points + 10;
            ScoreCounter.Text = Convert.ToString(points);
        }
        else
        {
            points = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreCounter.Text);
            points = points - 10;
            ScoreCounter.Text = Convert.ToString(points);
            timer4.Start();
        }
    }
 }

 private void Dupcard1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Dupcard1.Image = Properties.Resources.car1;
     if (usedCard1 == null)
     {
         usedCard1 = Dupcard1;
     }
     else if (usedCard1 != null && usedCard2 == null)
     {
         usedCard2 = Dupcard1;
     }
     if (usedCard1 != null && usedCard2 != null)
     {
         if (usedCard1.Tag == usedCard2.Tag)
         {
              usedCard1 = null;
              usedCard2 = null;
              Card1.Enabled = false;
              Dupcard1.Enabled = false;
              points = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreCounter.Text);
              points = points + 10;
              ScoreCounter.Text = Convert.ToString(points);
         }
         else
         {
              points = Convert.ToInt32(ScoreCounter.Text);
              points = points - 10;
              ScoreCounter.Text = Convert.ToString(points);
              timer4.Start();
         }
     }
 }

private void Win()
{
    foreach(PictureBox picture in cardsHolder.Controls)
    {
         if(picture != null)
         {

         }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("You've matched all cards", "Congratulations");
    Close();
}
```

PS: cardsHolder is the name of the panel, and Win is the method of triggering message when player wins the game.

Comment: How do you keep track of which cards were matched?

Comment: @Robin Could you post the rules of the game so I can better understand what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you set the `PictureBox.Image` property to `null` if you don't show an image on a `PictureBox`. So simply check that property:

```
private void Win()
{
    if (cardsHolder.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Any(pb => pb.Image == null))
        return;

    MessageBox.Show("You matched all the icons!", "Congratulations");
    Close(); 
}
```

`OfType<PictureBox>` selects all `PictureBox`es from the `Controls` collection and `Any` returns `true` if one of them has no `Image`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have added  other image to mask the image.

Comment: So I suggest you try to _separate your business (game) logic from the ui_, which is generally a good idea. Keep the _state_ of the game in a class designed for that and update your images according to that state. This way it will also be easier to reuse your code if you decide to use another ui like a website instead of winforms (just a theoretial hint of course).